# Solve the system for $x_1, x_2, x_3 $ when $\lambda = 1$

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcl}
2x_1 & - & x_2 & & & = & \lambda x_1\\
2x_1 & - & x_2 & + & x_3 & = & \lambda x_2\\
-2x_1 & + & 2x_2 & + & x_3 & = & \lambda x_3\end{array}$$

So when $\lambda = 1$ we have

$$\begin{array}{1}
\,\,\,\,2x_1 - \,\,x_2 \quad\quad\,\, = x_1\\
\,\,\,\, 2x_1 - \,\,x_2 + x_3 \,= x_2\\
-2x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = x_3
\end{array}$$

So then I brought over the right-hand side to the left-handside.

$$\begin{array}{1}
\,\,\,\,\,\,x_1 - \,\,x_2 \quad\quad\,\,\,\, = 0\\
\,\,\,\, 2x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3 \,= 0\\
-2x_1 + 2x_2 + \quad\,\,\, = 0
\end{array}$$

So now I reduced it go get the following augmented matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

From here I'm stuck because the answer in the back of the book says that
$x_1 = x_2 = -\frac12 s$, $x_3 = s$

I thought it would have been more like:
$x_1 = x_2 = s$, $x_3 = 0$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use the array environment in MathJax if you're not going to use alignment tabs?

Comment: Well I have only 111 points, I'm sure there is a lot that I'm doing wrong here, apart from my maths. So are you saying I should be using the format that you corrected me with? @MichaelHardy

Comment: Are you referring to the {rcrcrcl} that you have put in? I will have to go and investigate this. @MichaelHardy

Comment: Ok, thanks @Michael. I have looked these arrays now, so right, centre and left justification. That would have come in handy instead of me putting all those \,\, in the array. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, the books is not.

If you plug in your solution to the original equation, you get

$2s-s=s\\
2s-s+0=s\\
-2s+2s+0=0$

and all three equations are correct.

---

On the other hand, if you plug in the book's solution, the first equation becomes

$$2\cdot(-\frac12)s -(-\frac12 s) = s$$
which, already, is clearly not true since it is equivalent to
$$\frac32 s = s$$ which is only ever true for $s=0$.

Comment: Do you mean "If you plug in your solution to the original equation, you get" , not "the books solution", @5xum

Comment: @Bucephalus Yeah, sorry. I edited my answer

Comment: oh nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the solution from the back of your book is not correct. Take $s=2$. From the solution from the back of your book, you get that a solution of the system (when $\lambda=1$) is $x_1=x_2=-1$ and $x_3=2$. But then $2x_1-x_2+x_3=1\neq2=x_3$.

Comment: Where did the very last $x_3$ come from @JoseCarlosSantos?

Comment: @Bucephalus I don't understand your question. I got that $2x_1-x_2+x_3=1$. But if the solution from your book was correct, then I should have obtained $x_3$, which happens to be equal to $2$.